# Python strange newline where no new line is written

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I'm trying to print out a medium sized list in Python and what I'm doing is printing out the entire list on one line to test the program to make sure the right data is being put in to the list in the right order. I read in 2 files and put all the data into 2 dictionaries. Then, I split the dictionaries into parts and put all the similar data into a list. I'm super new to Python and this is a tutorial I found on dictionaries and I'm a little stuck. This line prints the list on one line:

```
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, player_list))
```

But this line prints each value of the list on a separate line which I don't want:

```
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, army_list))
```

Here's my code if needed that adds to the list:

```
import collections
import operator
terridict = {}
gsdict = {}
terr_list = []
player_list = []
army_list = []
list_length = []
total_territories = 0
with open('territories.txt', 'r') as territory:
    for line in territory:
        terridict["territory"], terridict["numeric_id"], terridict["continent"] = line.split(',')

with open('gameState.txt', 'r') as gameState:
    for line in gameState:
        gsdict["numeric_id"], gsdict["player"], gsdict["num_armies"] = line.split(',')
        terr_num = gsdict["numeric_id"]
        player_num = gsdict["player"]
        army_size = gsdict["num_armies"]
        if terr_num >= 1 and player_num >= 1 and army_size >= 1:
            terr_list.append(terr_num)
            player_list.append(player_num)
            army_list.append(army_size)
            player_list.sort()
            counter = collections.Counter(player_list)
            print (counter)
            total_territories = total_territories + 1
        x = counter
        sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
        counter = sorted_x
        print terr_num, player_num, army_size

print counter
print "Number of territories: %d" % total_territories
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, terr_list))
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, player_list))
print '[%s]' % ', '.join(map(str, army_list))
```

Comment: Does it have to be on only one line? If you are really only trying to find out if they are in the right order, just loop through the list. It will give you the first values to the last.
    `for i in player_list:
        print i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line`, when you read it in, ends with a newline. For example (I'm guessing here):

```
"1 nelson2013 23\n"
```

When you `split` it by space, you get this:

```
["1", "nelson2013", "23\n"]
```

Notice that the player name does not end with a newline, but army size does. When you join army sizes together, they end up like this:

```
"23\n, 18\n, 121\n"
```

i.e. separated by newlines, which makes them print one per line.

To combat this, you want to invoke [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) on `line` immediately at the top of the loop, before you process it any further.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! I found if I set line = line.rstrip(), it worked. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to fix what line is now because line.rsplit() doesn't work very well by itself. Building off what Amadan said:

```
line = line.rsplit()
```

This way, the new line character is removed and line can be set to a condition where the newline character is not involved. I tried it out and this worked.